How to restrict parent accounts availability according to the account type?
I have an account hierarchy, that is dependant on the account type(not record type).

'Role' on the image is a picklist, that is actually 'Type'.
I need to limit the list of accounts for the parent account field, so that if the account has a role 'Site', the parent account list should be limited only to the accounts with the role 'Sold to' and so on. Is it possible without coding an APEX class?

Hopefully this helps..

Create a new text field on Account called RoleFormula
Create a new Before-Save flow (Fast Field Updates) on Account which will populated the RoleFormula field based on your logic. If the current record's Role is 'Site', RoleFormula is set to 'Sold to'
Create a Lookup filter on Parent Account field where the criteria would be Parent Account: Role EQUALS Account: RoleFormula

We are using a regular text field instead of a formula is because the lookup filters do not accept formulas on the Right hand side criteria.
